# Getter returns no value

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble using setters and getters. When I tried to call a private var from a class to another class, I do not get the value of the var.
Here are some snippets of my code for you guys to check out.

This is my setter getter for the variable.

```
class PlayerStats

    private string _pName;
    public string pName
    { get { return _pName; } set { _pName = value; } }
}
```

This is where I want to show my var.

```
 public void Welcome()
    {
        PlayerStats pStats = new PlayerStats();
        Header();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        Console.WriteLine(pStats.pName);

    }
```

This is the method where I inserted a value on my var (this method is executed first before the method welcome)

```
        public void Username()
    {
        PlayerStats pStats = new PlayerStats();
        string name;
        Header();
        Console.Write("\nChoose your USERNAME: ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        pStats.pName = name;
    }
```

None of this are running from the main method. I thought of doing my program by just calling out different methods from different classes in the main method so it kinda looks like this:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Jobs jobCl = new Jobs();
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.Header();
        gui.StartPage();
        gui.Username();
        gui.ChoosepJob();
        gui.Welcome();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

When I call the var from the username method, I have no problem printing it but I cant make it to print if I am to call it from other methods.

Thank you for any help you can provide. Also if you can suggest a different way of doing this, please don't hesitate to say it to me

Comment: In both the username and the welcome methods you create a new instance of the PlayerStats class which is scoped as local to that method, you need to use the same instance in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make a new `PlayerStats` every method, make it once outside of the methods then pass it in to each one. You likely have the same problem with `Jobs` and that likely needs to be passed in to `ChoosepJob`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PlayerStats pStats = new PlayerStats();
    Jobs jobCl = new Jobs();
    GUI gui = new GUI();
    gui.Header();
    gui.StartPage();
    gui.Username(pStats);
    gui.ChoosepJob(jobCl);
    gui.Welcome(pStats);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public void Welcome(PlayerStats pStats)
{
    Header();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    Console.WriteLine(pStats.pName);

}

public void Username(PlayerStats pStats)
{
    string name;
    Header();
    Console.Write("\nChoose your USERNAME: ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    pStats.pName = name;
}
```

Comment: This really helped. I gotta remind myself to put the instantiation in the main method and that adding instantiates in every method is not a "playing safe" thing to do

Answer (score 0):

Your printing method here is creating a new instance of `PlayerStats`

```
public void Welcome()
{
    PlayerStats pStats = new PlayerStats();
    Header();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    Console.WriteLine(pStats.pName);

}
```

The one you're creating in here is not being used in `Welcome()` method

```
public void Username()
{
    PlayerStats pStats = new PlayerStats();
    string name;
    Header();
    Console.Write("\nChoose your USERNAME: ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    pStats.pName = name;
}
```

Create one instance in your main to follow through like the following:

```
public string Username()
{
    Header();
    Console.Write("\nChoose your USERNAME: ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    return name;
}

public void Welcome(PlayerStats pStats)
{
    Header();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    Console.WriteLine(pStats.pName);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PlayerStats pStats = new PlayerStats();

    Jobs jobCl = new Jobs();
    GUI gui = new GUI();
    gui.Header();
    gui.StartPage();
    pStats.pName = gui.Username();
    gui.ChoosepJob();
    gui.Welcome(pStats);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```